# Pica: cannot use getImageData on canvas, make sure fingerprinting protection isn't enabled

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I am getting this error while using `npm pica` library. I want to resize image using this library. Have tried two ways
I. by passing image url directly to `pica.resize(imageurl, canvas)` and
II. by passing image buffer to `pica.resize(imageBuffer,canvas)`. But it shows error Pica: cannot use getImageData on canvas, make sure fingerprinting protection isn't enabled. when I run code.

```js
// Convert Base64 to BufferArray
    const buf = Buffer.from(img, 'base64');

    let binary = '';
    const chunk = 8 * 1024;
    let i;
    for (i = 0; i < buf.length / chunk; i += 1) {
      binary += String.fromCharCode.apply(null, [
        ...buf.slice(i * chunk, (i + 1) * chunk),
      ]);
    }
    binary += String.fromCharCode.apply(null, [...buf.slice(i * chunk)]);

    // Dimensions for the image
    const width = 1200;
    const height = 627;

    // Instantiate the canvas object
    const can = canvas.createCanvas(width,height);
    // const context = canvas.getContext("2d");
    console.log(binary)
    
    pica.resize(binary, can)
        .then(result => console.log(result));
```

Comment: Which browser or platform are you running this code in? If it's Brave, you can turn shields off, which will disable fingerprint protection. I ran into this issue recently and use a fallback if I encounter this error with pica. There's currently no way around it: https://github.com/nodeca/pica/issues/229

Comment: No, I am getting this error in chrome.

Comment: Getting the same in firefox